# Tensorflow object-detection overload my system

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, object-detection

I have achieved from yesterday my first trial to train one modele :

```html
python object_detection/legacy/train.py --train_dir=CP --pipeline_config_path=faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config
```

After few times (10 or 20 secondes ) i am no more able to enter something with the mouth or key board. Update of GPU (nvidia-smi) is freeze.
After few minutes i did a reset, and verify the content of CP. It is no more empty. 
What I can see, it is that hard drive is all the time working.

I did the same a second time, but let the process continue till the morning. CP directory has been updated (till model.ckpt-491).

Now few word to describe my configuration :
CPU : i5
RAM : 8 giga
OS : Ubuntu 18.04
GPU 1 : GT 730 used for visualisation
GPU 2 : GTX 1060

ncvv : V9.0
and nvidia-smi give :

> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   | NVIDIA-SMI 390.87                 Driver Version: 390.87                    |
>   |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>   | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
>   | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
>   |===============================+======================+======================|
>   |   0  GeForce GT 730      Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
>   | N/A   34C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    703MiB /  2001MiB |     N/A      Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>   |   1  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
>   |  0%   33C    P8     4W / 120W |      2MiB /  6078MiB |      0%      Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Initially i have installed every thing to work only with one GPU (GT 730, as I did not have the second one at this time). 
Yesterday I received the new video card, and without doing something, it was recognize by nvidia-smi, and it was used directly by Tensorflow. Without any other modification.

Now my questions :

- the fact that i did not install a driver for this new card could be the issue (I did not use it for visualisation) ?
- or some point in the config file (I reduce the maxsize to 600*480) and lower batch_size to 1 could be modified to avoid my issue ?

Thanks you for your help
Jean-Marie

Answer (score 0):

I buy more RAM (total 24 giga), and this time execution is fast. No more impossibility to use my computer. Even more I am able to increase image size !

Probably somethink evident for most of you. But that just in case of some one add the same issue.